# Обращение к вложенным классам из XAML разметки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

В XAML разметке есть список ListBox. Мне нужно, чтобы в зависимости от типа объекта, который передаётся в список из коллекции, выбирался шаблон, при помощи которого элемент будет отображаться в списке.

Список выглядит следующим образом:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:People}">
                <!-- Шаблон для типа People -->
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
                <!-- Шаблон для типа Car -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

В данном случае программа работает корректно. Но если я хочу обратиться к типу не напрямую из пространства имён (допустим, нужный мне класс находится внутри другого), то обратиться к данному классу и получить его я не могу.

К примеру, я хочу обратиться к классу A из библиотеки ALib, файла A.cs:

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    {

    }
}
```

Так я подключу пространство имён и смогу обратиться к нужному мне классу.

```
xmlns:ans="clr-namespace:ALib;assembly=ALib"

...

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ans:A}">
```

Но как мне обратиться к классу B в данном случае, учитывая, что в библиотеке ALib я не могу ничего менять?

Пробовал обращаться к классу B с помощью конструкции ans:A.B, но всё безуспешно.

*Я только начал изучение WPF и XAML. Возможно, ответ очевиден, или есть более простое решение. Может вообще не стоит так делать. Если это так, предложите свои варианты. Буду очень благодарен.*

Comment: Использование вложенных типов - плохая практика, вы уверены, что класс Б определен внутри класса А? Вы точно ничего не перепутали? А так, возможно `{x:Type ans:(A.B)}` прокатит.

Comment: Чтоб знать то, что туда писать, воспользуйтесь простым `typeof(B)`, примерно [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K2ETTg), увидите `A+B`, ну вот и пишите `local:A+B`, правда дизайнеру я думаю это ой как не понравиться....

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `DataTemplateSelector` .

```
public class TemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        
        if (item.GetType() ==typeof(A) )
            return element.FindResource("templateA") as DataTemplate;
        else 
            return element.FindResource("templateB") as DataTemplate;

    }
}
```

XAML

```
 <Window.Resources>
      <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector"/> 
</Window.Resources>
 .
 .
 .
<ListBox  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
```